# Django User Logging In System | Views.py doesn't work

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

I am currently making a user authentication system. I have a login screen with a couple of input fields. I can log the values of the input fields to the console in my javascript. I send the data to my backend. Submitting doesn't work and in my views.py loggin the data to the console too. I can basically completely remove the views.py function and the Template is shown anyway! Is that because I am using the Django Authentication Urls, so the registration folder is the default for the django registration? How can I send that to my backend? I have my logging in template (https://pastebin.com/RKe5ECps)

**Views.py**

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('forum')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("There was an error Loggin in, Try Again!"))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Folder Structure:
templates/registration/login.html
templates/registration/signup.html

I tried removing the authentication, but than i couldn't see anything, because at the login/ url there was nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have not linked your view in your urls. So now you are using the built-in views in `django.contrib.auth` you need to explicitly add your view.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path("login/", login_user, name="login"),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Ok, now it works, but the views.py doesn't work. I can't print something, I don't get redirected to another page. Like in the code. That's my problem at the moment.

Comment: With the code you provided it looks like you do the post request in JS instead of using a <form method="post"> tag, so you have to handle the request response and redirection yourself in javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) it's not trivial and not related to django.

Comment: Ok, nice to know. I'll implement a form ig. I hope this works :D